# cURL wrap url containing token having forward slashes

Tags: url, curl, escaping, special-characters

I have an URL with token having forward slashes like: `https://blahblah/blahblahblah/blah=@server.com/something/somewhere/report/view/51234-5678-9101`

Replacing `/` with `%2F` or `_` doesn't work as it is changing token from the point of view of server. Is there any other way I could smuggle `/` in the URL?

Comment: if you run in your browser's javascript console ```encodeURIComponent("@server.com/something/somewhere/report/view/51234-5678-9101")```  you will get ```%40server.com%2Fsomething%2Fsomewhere%2Freport%2Fview%2F51234-5678-9101``` , hence the correct url should be: ```https://blahblah/blahblahblah/blah=%40server.com%2Fsomething%2Fsomewhere%2Freport%2Fview%2F51234-5678-9101```

Comment: @hanshenrik No, it fails on forward slash in token: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: blahblah` and if I replace forward slashes in token with `%2F` to make it looking like `https://blahblah%2Fblahblahblah%2Fblah=@server.com...` then I am getting 401 from server as this is not the valid token.

Comment: @Madhurjya of course. Double, single it doesn't make any difference. Also tried `-H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN"` `OAuth`, `Token`, nothing.

Comment: Is `=` part of the token?

Comment: @Madhurjya, yes it is.

Comment: @Syn did you try by encoding that as well?

Comment: @Madhurjya, no that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

URL encoding is the solution for this problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159253/decoding-url-encoding-percent-encoding